# jquery Sortable Multiply Lists saving to mySQL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I believe the issue is that I am not getting a id numbers passing the serialize? the response I'm getting from the php look like:

```
Array 
( 
    [sort1]=> menu[]=1&menu[]=2&menu2[]=3
    [sort2]=> menu2[]=4
)
```

shouldn't each menu item be numbered like: menu[0], menu[1] etc...?

below is my code..

```
$(function() 
{
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable(
    {
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    update : function () 
    { 
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "sort_menu.php",
            data: 
            {
                sort1:$("#sortable1").sortable('serialize'),
                sort2:$("#sortable2").sortable('serialize')
            },
            error: function(res)
            {
            alert("theres an error "+ res);
            },
            success: function(res)
            {
            alert("theres a response "+ res);
            }
        });
    } 
    });
});
```

the php:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE crew='1' ORDER BY sort ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<li id=\"menu_".$row['id']."\">".$row['title']."</li>\n";
}
```

and the form receiving the ajax information

```
print_r($_POST);

$menu = $_REQUEST['sort1'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {
mysql_query("UPDATE menu SET sort=" . $i . ", list='1' WHERE id='" . $menu[$i] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Avoid `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: noted, but I do not think that is where the issue is?